# How do I calculate box bound collision between two scaled items in openGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Both of the items are using different scales (e.g. item 1 = gl.glScalef(.25f, .25f, 1f) where as item 2 = gl.glScalef(.10f, .10f, 1f))

For detecting the collision between the two items, am I correct in assuming for the width and height values I use the scaled values ?? e.g. for item 1, the width is .25f?

Answer (score 0):

I would transform the coordinates and sizes to world versions, and then use them to check for collisions, that way a simple transformation to convert from local to world coordinates ([examples available here](http://sourceforge.net/p/openantz/wiki/Local_to_World_Coordinates/)) and calculate sizes based on world dimenensions and you should be fine.

Let me know if you need more information:)